# How to use $watch stable way

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

I have following code

front_controller

```
$scope.month=monthNames[$scope.currentmonthnumber];
monthyeartransfer.setvalue($scope.month);

$scope.monthchange = function(m) {
   $scope.month = m;
   monthyeartransfer.setvalue($scope.month);
}
```

In this above controller i update month value into `monthyeartransfer` service on every click.

I am getting this `profilecontroller` following way

profilecontroller

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
   $scope.month = monthyeartransfer.getvalue();
}
```

But the above code trigger each action. but it only need to happen when month value changes in service.

i tried like.

```
$scope.$watch('month',function(){
    $scope.month = monthyeartransfer.getvalue();
}
```

But its Not working. How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to watch the result of a function:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
   return monthyeartransfer.getvalue();
}, function (val) {
    // Do stuff...
});
```